# How to use local variables from loop and assign them to equations from other structs

Tags: c#, if-statement, for-loop

```
private void ParametersChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (AreArgumentsValid() && klasaBetonaComboBox.SelectedItem != null)
    {

        var _dMed = Convert.ToDouble(MomentSavijanjaMed.Text);                   
        var  _dh = Convert.ToDouble(VisinaPresjekaH.Text);
        var _db = Convert.ToDouble(SirinaPresjekaB.Text);
        var _dd1 = Convert.ToDouble(UdaljenostArmD1.Text);
        var _dd = _dh - _dd1;
        var _dFck = Convert.ToDouble(fck.Text);
        var _gamaC = 1.50;
        gamaCRezultat.Text = _gamaC.ToString();
        var dFcd =  _dFck /_gamaC;
        FcdRezultat.Text = dFcd.ToString();

        var _dMiSd = _dMed * 1000 / (_dd * _dd * _db * dFcd);

        rezultat.Text = _dMiSd.ToString("F4");
    }
```

from here i need to use variable `_dMiSd` and `_dd` in next struct.

```
private void deformacijaCelikaComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double epsilonC2;
    double ksiRacunski;
    double zetaRacunska;
    double kARacunski;
    double epsilonC2pretpostavka;
    double miSdCrtica;
    double alphaVRacunski;
    double selectedDeformacija = ((NovaDeformacijaArmature)deformacijaCelikaComboBox.SelectedItem).epsilonCelika;
    double zeta;
    double ksi;
    double xNeutralnaOs;
    double zKrakSila;

    if (selectedDeformacija == 20.0)
    {
        for (epsilonC2pretpostavka = 0.01; epsilonC2pretpostavka <=3.5 ; epsilonC2pretpostavka += 0.01)
        {
            ksiRacunski = epsilonC2pretpostavka / (selectedDeformacija + epsilonC2pretpostavka);

            if (epsilonC2pretpostavka <= 2)
            {
                kARacunski = 8 - epsilonC2pretpostavka / (4 * (6 - epsilonC2pretpostavka));
                alphaVRacunski = (epsilonC2pretpostavka * (6 - epsilonC2pretpostavka)) / 12;
            }
            else if (epsilonC2pretpostavka <= 3.5)
            {
                kARacunski = (epsilonC2pretpostavka * (3 - epsilonC2pretpostavka - 4) + 2) / (2 * epsilonC2pretpostavka * (3 * epsilonC2pretpostavka - 2));
                alphaVRacunski = (3 * epsilonC2pretpostavka - 2) / (3 * epsilonC2pretpostavka);
            }

            zetaRacunska = 1 - (kARacunski * ksiRacunski);
            miSdCrtica = 0.85 * alphaVRacunski * ksiRacunski * zetaRacunska;

            if (Math.Abs(miSdCrtica-_dMiSd)<0.0001)
            {
                epsilonC2pretpostavka = epsilonC2;
                zetaRacunska = zeta;
                ksiRacunski = ksi;
                xNeutralnaOs = ksi * _dd;
                zKrakSila = zeta * _dd;
            }
```

here i got for loop as you see. Inside of it i have if case which would give me values for variables `kAracunski` and `alphaVracunski`.

When i get them from calculation i want to use them for calculation `miSdCrtica`.

After that i want to check does their difference satisfy given condition.

I get an error:

> "Variables does not exist in current context (for `_dMiSd` and `_dd`).

And error

> "Use of unassigned variable alphaVRacunski and `zetaRacunski`.

How to link them up together?

Simple example

```
private void something(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double a=3;
            double b=6;
            double c;
            double d;

            if (a>5)
            {
                c = a + b;
            }
            d = c * 5;
```

variable c is unassigned and it can't be used...how can i use it?
I understand it is pretty dummy question and solution is probabily pretty simple but I am really new in programming and need some time to tie things together. My appologies

Comment: It depends a lot on the relationship between those two methods. Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's impossible to know for sure what that is. By the way, if you plan on doing a lot more sharing of your code with English speaking people, you might want to consider avoiding as much as possible the three-letter sequence "fck", which is one letter away from a fairly rude word. :)

Comment: Could you please provide a simple example with **simple** variable names which demonstrate your problem/question? Don't expect us to work with all these weird names to even _understand_ what you try to do!

Comment: Btw, you're overusing the `var` keyword. Rule of thumbs: Use it whenever the type is obvious.

Comment: As for the second question, you should just post it as a separate question. It has nothing to do with the first one. Of course, neither really fits the stack overflow question format, but if people don't like that, they'll just vote for closure :) In any case, ask yourself "How can I use the value of `c` in a calculation if it hasn't been assigned any value in the first place?" The whole code quite strongly implies you're just trying to write a set of equations into C# - you need to think a bit more procedurally in C#. Or write it as a set of functions instead of sequential commands :)

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring them outside of the area your modifying their value in and declare them as integers or doubles.

```
    internal int _dMisd;
    internal int _dd;

private void ParametersChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (AreArgumentsValid() && klasaBetonaComboBox.SelectedItem != null)
{

    _dMed = Convert.ToDouble(MomentSavijanjaMed.Text);                   
    _dh = Convert.ToDouble(VisinaPresjekaH.Text);
    _db = Convert.ToDouble(SirinaPresjekaB.Text);
    _dd1 = Convert.ToDouble(UdaljenostArmD1.Text);
    _dd = _dh - _dd1;
    _dFck = Convert.ToDouble(fck.Text);
    _gamaC = 1.50;
    gamaCRezultat.Text = _gamaC.ToString();
    dFcd =  _dFck /_gamaC;
    FcdRezultat.Text = dFcd.ToString();

    _dMiSd = _dMed * 1000 / (_dd * _dd * _db * dFcd);

    rezultat.Text = _dMiSd.ToString("F4");
}
}
```

Why are you declaring numbers as 'var' anyway??

EDIT: Declare c and d outside of the function

```
        double c;
        double d;

private void something(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double a=3;
        double b=6;
        if (a>5)
        {
            c = a + b;
        }
        d = c * 5;
   }
```

Comment: Passing method arguments using fields / global variables? Really? :D

Comment: @Luaan I'm a newb. Newb solutions work for me. I'm sure there are much more sophisticated ways to do things. I'm trying to learn them all the time. But alas, I'm only a man :-D

Comment: Well, it might look simple to you now, but it greatly expands the problem space - good luck maintaining that (or god forbid, writing automated tests). There are places where using state classes makes sense, but *especially* as a new programmer, you want to try a bit more structured approach first. Passing arguments and using meaningful objects / classes shouldn't really be considered an advanced technique in 2015 :)